# Адаптивная яндекс карта

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

**Как сделать адаптивную яндекс карту?** Использую апи 2.1 янекс карт. Возникла проблема, карту видно только при фиксированных размерах `width` и `height`(max-width max-height не сработали). Пробовал установить `width=100%` в `src` скрипта,

```
<script
      src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&width=100%&height=100%;apikey=7839060c-62ef-4cbb-ba42-c22fee08535a"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
```

но как-будто не то сделал.

Comment: Размеры надо не карте задавать, а блоку, в который она встраивается. Размеры блока при этом могут быть и относительными — width=100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myMap.events.add('sizechange', function () {
    myMap.container.fitToViewport();
});
```